# How to make this an expandable typescript type?

Tags: typescript

I have a `MeasurementData` type that looks like this.

```js
type MeasurementData = {
  measurements: {
    x: number | Date;
    y: number;
  }[];

  xUnits: string;
  xFirstValue: number;
  xLastValue: number;
  xSecondToLastValue: number;
  xAverage: number;
  xMin: number;
  xMax: number;
  xDelta: number;

  yUnits: string;
  yFirstValue: number;
  yLastValue: number;
  ySecondToLastValue: number;
  yAverage: number;
  yMin: number;
  yMax: number;
  yDelta: number;
};
```

But now the `measurements` section is going to expand with a possible unknown number of `y` values.
e.g.

```js
measurements: {
  x: number | Date;
  y0: number;
  y1: number;
  y2: number;
  y3: number;
  y4: number;
  y5: number;
}[];
```

Being new to typescript I'm not sure how to expand `MeasurementData` to handle this scenario.

How do you make it so you don't repeat all the y calculations definitions?
e.g. - I don't want to do this.

```
y0Units: string;
y0FirstValue: number;
y0LastValue: number;
y0SecondToLastValue: number;
y0Average: number;
y0Min: number;
y0Max: number;
y0Delta: number;

y1Units: string;
y1FirstValue: number;
y1LastValue: number;
y1SecondToLastValue: number;
y1Average: number;
y1Min: number;
y1Max: number;
y1Delta: number;

y2Units: string;
y2FirstValue: number;
y2LastValue: number;
y2SecondToLastValue: number;
y2Average: number;
y2Min: number;
y2Max: number;
y2Delta: number;

/// y3, y4, y5 ...etc...
```

Comment: Usually when you find numbers or ordinals in your variable names (e.g. a1, a2, a3, or first_x, second_x, third_x) that means you really want an array / list.

Comment: Are the `Units` properties really `string` for `x` and `number` for all the `y`?

Comment: @jcalz No. The units are all `string`. Updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh, this is kind of a nightmare type.  It is sort of almost possible, but I *beg* you to refactor your data type to make use of arrays instead of an increasingly long list of property keys with numbers inside the name of the key.  But I enjoy making TypeScript do terrible things, so here goes:

You want `MeasurementData` to be the infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of all versions of the structure for the different numbers of `y` properties.  Like `MeasurementDataElement<0> | MeasurementDataElement<0 | 1> | MeasurementDataElement<0 | 1 | 2> | MeasurementDataElement<0 | 1 | 2 | 3> | ...`.

You can't really do *infinite* unions. You can either do it as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints), or as a union of up to some finite number.  I'm going to do the latter and pick, say, `40`, so you can support `y0` through `y39`.

Because this involves string concatenation and recursion, I'll be using the TypeScript 4.1 beta. TypeScript 4.1 will support [template literal types and mapped type key augmentation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) as well as [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002):

```
type CommonSuffixProps = {
  Units: string;
  FirstValue: number;
  LastValue: number;
  SecondToLastValue: number;
  Min: number;
  Max: number;
  Delta: number;
}

type CommonPrefixes<N extends number> = 'x' | `y${N}`

type MeasurementDataElement<N extends number> = Pick<
  { measurements: { [K in CommonPrefixes<N>]: ('x' extends K ? Date : never) | number }[]; } &
  { [K in keyof CommonSuffixProps as `${CommonPrefixes<N>}${K}`]: CommonSuffixProps[K] },
  'measurements' | `x${keyof CommonSuffixProps}` | (N extends any ? `y${N}${keyof CommonSuffixProps}` : never)
> extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;

type TuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<N extends number, A extends number[] = []> =
  N extends A['length'] ? A : TuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<N, [...A, A[number] | A['length']]>;

type MeasurementDataForTuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<VN extends { [k: number]: number }> = {
  [K in keyof VN]: MeasurementDataElement<Extract<VN[K], number>>
}[number]

// only works up to maximum number of 40 (y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, ... y38, y39)
type MeasurementData = MeasurementDataForTuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<TuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<40>>
```

That is *A BIG MESS*  and I'm not sure it's worth explaining in detail.  I'll give the highlights:

- You can probably see that `CommonSuffixProps` looks like the things you want to add to the end of `x` and `y0` and `y1` etc.
- The `CommonPrefixes<N>` type turns `0 | 1 | 2` into `'x' | 'y0' | 'y1' | 'y2'`
- The `MeasurementDataElement<N>` type turns `0 | 1` into the type you're looking for where its `measurements` property is `{x: number | Date, y0: number, y1: number}[]` and where its other properties all look like combining the `CommonPrefixes<0 | 1>` with the `CommonSuffixProps`.
- The `TuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<N>` type turns `4` into the tuple `[0, 0|1, 0|1|2, 0|1|2|3]`.  I'm using this so we can turn a single number like `40` into the big list of possible sets of `y` property sets we want.
- The `MeasurementDataForTuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<T>` takes one of those tuples-of-unions-of-numbers from before and gives you the union of `MeasurementDataElement<N>` for all the `N` in there.
- Finally, `MeasurementData` is just `MeasurementDataForTuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<TuplesOfUnionsOfNumbers<40>>`, or the type we're looking for.

---

This type is *so annoying* to inspect with IntelliSense.  Let's say we take `MeasurementData` and look at the single union element with a `y1Min` property but no `y2Min` property:

```
type Example = Extract<Exclude<MeasurementData, {y2Min: any}>, {y1Min: any}>;
/* type Example = {
    measurements: {
        x: number | Date;
        y0: number;
        y1: number;
    }[];
    xUnits: string;
    xFirstValue: number;
    xLastValue: number;
    xSecondToLastValue: number;
    xMin: number;
    xMax: number;
    xDelta: number;
    y0Units: string;
    y0FirstValue: number;
    y0LastValue: number;
    y0SecondToLastValue: number;
    ... 9 more ...;
    y1Delta: number;
} */
```

That looks right, I guess?  As further evidence, let's try doing some tests on a value of type `MeasurementData`:

```
declare const md: MeasurementData;
if ("y23Min" in md) {
  md.y14SecondToLastValue.toFixed(2);
  for (let m of md.measurements) {
    m.y19.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

By testing if `y23Min` is in the value, the compiler knows it is one of the union elements with at least 24 `y` coordinates, so it will let you index into, say, `y14SecondToLastValue` or `measurements[0].y19`.

Hooray!

---

There you go. Again, I *implore* you not to use this type.  Instead, I strongly suggest that you refactor into a more TypeScript-friendly data structure.  Maybe something like this?

```
interface Friendly<Y extends CommonSuffixProps[]> {
  measurements: { x: number, y: { [K in keyof Y]: number } }[],
  axisProperties: { x: CommonSuffixProps, y: Y }
}
function acceptFriendly<Y extends CommonSuffixProps[]>(f: Friendly<[...Y]>) { }

declare const axisProps: CommonSuffixProps;
acceptFriendly({
  measurements: [
    { x: 0, y: [1, 2, 3] },
    { x: 1, y: [2, 3, 4] }
  ],
  axisProperties: {
    x: axisProps,
    y: [axisProps, axisProps, axisProps]
  }
})
```

It's a generic constraint for the number of `y` properties, and otherwise we are changing `y3Min` to something like `axisProperties.y[3].Min`.  This can be iterated over more easily too, right?  But ultimately it's up to you whether you want to refactor.  Even if you don't want to, I can't really recommend the Frankenstein's Monster of a type above.  Please consider this a cautionary tale instead of a solution.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201015#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgZQK4DMsEsAeACgE5xgDOUAvFAN4BQUUAqirsOQFxTnDG4oA5gG5GUAGK5ivAGoBDADYYI3FBgQAjCMVFMAMnNmLlq9Vp1i0EAMaoAJgBU4Bo0pVQ1m7bqgBZAaZeFky+cviB5j4AIhAKwHIR3vQAvvT0oJCwiMgoJBB4+BDkADwAclAQ+MAQKHaUnuYAfNRQAOT4rVAAPlAABiAAJLSlyb1pGdC+EIYYxBAINcBRcvEAogrzi2UVVTV1HmbazTSEuNYA1sVitFALM3MLKBzcNwDaANJQAllIqHkFRTKjQAutwABTtTqVaq1SifAD8UGW1SgqggADdtABKboHIJQZKvYHCAlQABk1ygHy+KCg5wgIDgWB+OUwOAIJDIlEMfSG8F+uTmAJKpUaySG71GoJZqDZBU5FA+wIJABoxK07uRZpsnuROj1evghvTGcz+azsPLSBRRriweVoXtuSgQFBEf0hiNjQymTL0JaOdbyLa0ZjiFj6M1HbCaVhtFAAPJuuhUz7fE2+hPShNK0mhpLpcDQBwYMAbcgJrCsXCoCtYUqHaTbaP7BraFVQACCOxhrcbRJaROOYgduxjnderQ2QmAAAtWsrEd3uCWy0VK9Xa5WG0ERR3XgA6I+djsTtvEZU9CdTmqCOcL4GNUSFzJTe46pYrOTiODEVfljc2C3etGxKGRR17Sg3nORIL1ggljjoMRqXTH1mXA6U3y1B5FmROR1g-YpViqYg5GsYBinApUO3PRpGhSV5z2BNIAHoWKgVAFFdAB3X9zkoUsoGAOBbjCXAEHUPFzA45kABYAAYoDBEB5I7EAAEY1IAJjUgBmNTZI7I8DygEBdIADj0gBOCMJj8aZsI-PCWiw7VHk-eIfz-UsAKrICUDrHdzBKf91z8msAu3UDigUujWJY+g7BsBQ5DmKBbAC4BbjsbhXJwp48NEXBmTBAAiEAtN0-wUFKmlspxBgmAQOwDw02SrAyxxnEMYB5DcA9hMkQo7DBLSsR8LBfyUjYsoQGTsoPTU3MWcgGrEJrWvUqyBrgIaIBGsafFSVIX2gYi5AQNcWmIvgyIo4jrCUJLijypyvw7G4Kuq7g5BdBCPtM9TvqgX7XWSJ96BYgAqISiygAAlFpGqYW4HOW3UXnWlGmHCKT4x6ZEIB8bGmBU2DiZJjTyaxwliSx-Bq2eHg+AEER6ckaReuMdxzwp-AXC5txqex-AOvsJwBb6kw8eCFH8GB3n6dCXHFZFmI4gSGWKZUxmuGZ-ghG1+SOdcaXVZRlTJe54WLfksXaglnqpZ5xsKeMqArNuX9oGM7X1PV+JqeSKAoYS+gBGqYgsDI6BxH4PYuOKABNHsnT9OVAy5IckKatH8qZm4VcbNSXlTOqM2ZJPpXPUlabVJgxPIBVtGAXAilL3HzVlAMiCDEuoBT476CwDAUHIiKQesawIDAYA47b2pE5TltKC7-12V7rPHzBLBuHnhOQGKQ8jyrxoGoJNIkse1LoAy3gQfwXAm6Dbg14zzeKFEMjp9n-fF5AMEyMlr5z1q8LGhduCqVMtwV4mkoA6SgLpZUyR64owgVAOBIAYEIP0lAWSyCxDAlQY3ZuxBW7txznLH6j9n5clQaTGBJC+4PyfgqcgHYmFcmYkwY6WIgA)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I learned a lot. At the end of the day I decided to completely refactor the data. 